# Automatically input password using script when installing Ruby with rvm install?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to use a LOCAL script to install ruby remotely on a server. Following is my code:

```
sshpass -p ****** ssh hx@$HOST 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'
    export PATH=$PATH:/home/hx/.rvm/bin/

    rvm install 2.2.0
ENDSSH
```

When I run this script, an error occurs saying:

```
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.2.0',
showing last 15 lines of /home/hx/.rvm/log/1423392690_ruby-2.2.0/update_system.log
++ [[ -d /usr/sbin ]]
++ [[ :/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/hx/.rvm/bin/:/home/hx/.rvm/bin: != *\:\/\u\s\r\/\s\b\i\n\:* ]]
++ for sbin_path in /sbin /usr/sbin /usr/local/sbin
++ [[ -d /usr/local/sbin ]]
++ [[ :/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/hx/.rvm/bin/:/home/hx/.rvm/bin: != *\:\/\u\s\r\/\l\o\c\a\l\/\s\b\i\n\:* ]]
++ [[ -n '' ]]
++ command_to_run=(__rvm_sudo -p "%p password required for '$*': " "${command_to_run[@]}")
++ __rvm_sudo -p '%p password required for '\''apt-get --quiet --yes update'\'': ' apt-get --quiet --yes update
++ command sudo -p '%p password required for '\''apt-get --quiet --yes update'\'': ' apt-get --quiet --yes update
++ sudo -p '%p password required for '\''apt-get --quiet --yes update'\'': ' apt-get --quiet --yes update
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
++ return 1
++ typeset __ret=1
++ case ${__ret} in
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
make: *** [install-ruby] Error 1
```

It turns out that when running rvm install as a non-root user, it will ask you to input the password to update apt-get DURING the process.

Is there a way to automatically input the password within my script? Like

```
echo password | apt-get -S install xxxxxx
```

Comment: Maybe `apt-get -S install smh < "password"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally not: sending passwords to [sudo](http://www.sudo.ws/) is not considered secure.  The error message points to the recommended solution: provide (configure) a program which will prompt you for the password.  With sudo, once you have given a valid password it remains in effect for several minutes (prolonged if you keep using the credentials before they time out).

For configuring, etc., this [summary of askpass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232121/set-environment-variable-ssh-askpass-or-askpass-in-sudoers-resp) seems helpful.

Here is another summary, with an example: [Graphically ask for password in a bash script and retain default sudo timeout setting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81181/graphically-ask-for-password-in-a-bash-script-and-retain-default-sudo-timeout-se).  The interesting thing is that its "askpass" program is a shell script which calls kdialog.  A similar example could be developed using "dialog", or even a bash script which used "read -p" to read a variable, or even -- simply echo the password as done in [How to use sudo inside of a Run Script build phase in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803329/how-to-use-sudo-inside-of-a-run-script-build-phase-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Could you tell me how to specify a askpass program?